# Graph API - reading message from shared mailbox with only message id (without mailboxId)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing outlook addin. Users select email from theirs mailboxes and then I get these messages through Graph API using message ids and process messages. Problem occurs when someone selects message from shared mailbox. I'm able to get message id using addin API but message is not available through graph api endpoint /me/messages/{message-id}. I know I can get this message through /users/{user-id}/messages/{message-id} but in this case I don't know shared mailbox id.

Is any way to get message without knowing mailbox id or any way to list shared mailboxes available for selected user so I could check if message is in any of them?

Comment: Do you know at least the mail address of the shared mailbox?

Comment: No, i know only user mail address. I know nothing about his shared mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently feature to get owner mailbox details in shared folder, when  Office.Context.Mailbox.item in null is not available. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.